# How to modify partition in FreeBSD 10 with gpart

Tags: freebsd, partition

I am using FreeBSD. My HDD has this set of partitions:

```
root@core:/media # gpart show
=>       63  390721905  ada0  MBR  (186G)
         63       1985        - free -  (993K)
       2048   13365248     1  !39  (6.4G)
   13367296         44        - free -  (22K)
   13367340  174063519     2  freebsd  [active]  (83G)
  187430859      57397        - free -  (28M)
  187488256  203231232     3  ebr  (97G)
  390719488         23        - free -  (12K)
  390719511       2394     4  freebsd  (1.2M)
  390721905         63        - free -  (32K)

=>        0  174063519  ada0s2  BSD  (83G)
          0  174063518       1  freebsd-ufs  (83G)
  174063518          1          - free -  (512B)

=>        0  203231232  ada0s3  EBR  (97G)
          0   14485504       1  linux-swap  (6.9G)
   14485504  188745728  229929  linux-data  (90G)

=>   0  2394  ada0s4  BSD  (1.2M)
     0  2394          - free -  (1.2M)
```

**I want to add swap drive to FreeBSD** by modifying linux swap. In fact I do not use linux drive at all, and don't care if it's removed.

I am doing this to modify partition:

```
root@core:/media # sudo gpart modify -i1 -t freebsd-swap ada0s3
gpart: pre-check failed: Operation canceled
```

What am I doing wrong? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: The output of `lsblk` could help me to give you a more precise answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I am understanding, that you already have one linux-swap partition (`ada0s3`).

If this is the case, just add the partition to `/etc/fstab`

If not, I recommend you to use `fdisk` for `MBR partition tables` or `gdisk` for `GPT partition tables` instead to **edit** the `partition table` as you want and then execute: `mkswap partition`, `swapon partition` and then add the partition to `/etc/fstab`.

**For example**

```
#add /dev/ada0s3 to /etc/fstab as swap partition
echo "/dev/ada0s3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 1):

The EBR partition type is well-known as "extended partition" or "logical partition" (it is an MBR-only type of partition and is pretty old; from good old MS-DOS days). This is not something that is typical on FreeBSD since logical partitions are made natively with `bsdlabel`.

From the [gpart(8) manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?gpart(8)):

> ```
>  MBR        Master Boot Record is used on PCs and removable media.
>             Requires the GEOM_PART_MBR kernel option.  The GEOM_PART_EBR
>             option adds support for the Extended Boot Record (EBR), which
>             is used to define a logical partition.  The
>             GEOM_PART_EBR_COMPAT option enables backward compatibility for
>             partition names in the EBR scheme.  It also prevents any type
>             of actions on such partitions.
> ```

The last sentence makes clear that FreeBSD's GEOM part module is going to block actions on this type of partitions. And you *should not add* `ada0s3` as swap because it is a *logical partition* and this might confuse other operating systems (even FreeBSD might have a problem then). And you surely don't intend to have a 97 GB swap partition, as far as I understood.

If you don't need the Linux system on the EBR at all, you can boot up a Linux live CD and remove the logical partition entirely using your favorite `fdisk` tool. Then it will be marked as free space and you can go back to FreeBSD and modify it with gpart.

**One further warning:** be careful that FreeBSD has installed its boot manager, because if the primary booting system is Linux, you may need to restore the boot loader with a FreeBSD live CD after deleting the EBR partition. Whatever you do, be sure you know what you do, because you can lose access to data or even irreversibly lose it. **Backups are always appropriate in such situations**.